# How to get paginated files from directory?

Tags: linux, command-line

Is it possible to list files from directory based on pagination scope.

for example.

```
ls 0,50
ls 50,100
ls 100,150
```

Actually we have ton of files inside directory and while displaying those files in view takes lot time if i display all files in one shot. instead i wanted to paginate result of files inside directory.

Comment: The term "lac" is not widely understood outside South-East Asia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
ls | tail -n <line number of the first line> | head -n <number of lines that you want>
```

e.g.

```
ls | tail -n 10 | head -n 20
```

Would display 20 filenames, starting at the 10th one.

Comment: I am not in favour of your solution because it actually loads the files and then does processing of start and end point on it. it should be consuming more time in loading all the files.

Comment: You do not understand - At the end of the day a directory is just a file with a list of filenames and their locations (inodes) on the disk. My solution does not load the files but parses that file that contains those details.

Answer (score 4):

```
ls /usr/bin | less
ls /usr/bin | pager
```

The `less` and `pager` commands let you scroll through the output. This only makes sense for viewing, not for packaging the output for other uses

If I'm only interested in a specific range, I would usually revert to perl:

```
ls /usr/bin | perl -ne 'print if $. ~~ [10..40]'
ls /usr/bin | perl -ne 'print if 10 .. 40'
```

Comment: Sandip (the OP) could replace `less` (or `more` or `most` or any `pager`) with a `sed` (or `awk` or mix of `head` and `tail`) command to splice the output of `ls`

Comment: The sed equivalent of that perl script is: `sed -n 10,40p`

Comment: @AlanCurry will it be loading all the files in memory first. because we have lac of files inside directory and we wanted to list those files using pagination

Comment: The perl and sed suggestions both work the same way, by reading the input and printing when the line counter is between 10 and 40. You can add a "quit" command at line 40 to make it stop reading there, which make it end faster, rather than read the rest of the input and ignore it. That would be `sed -n -e10,40p -e40q`. I don't understand exactly what you mean by "pagination". To me, that means "use a pager" i.e. `less`.